# Paths with assemble and swig

Tags: path, gruntjs, swig-template, assemble

i have a project running grunt with assemble and swig as the engine for templating. i need to know how to handle paths for my navigation, because i want to store some files in subfolders.

i just found this for assemble: http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-path.html
but that doesn't work for me, it says "Warning: Unexpected string Use".

anyone knows a solution for that? do you need any further information?

Comment: I changed the tag from "swig" to "swig-template" since "swig" is for SWIG at www.swig.org, whereas you are using the swig at http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/, which is "swig-template".

Comment: The syntax provided in the documentation is not valid Swig syntax. I don't know the correct answer, but you might try: `{{ _dirname(path) }}` if the helper is a plain function or `{% _dirname path %}` if it's actually being injected into Swig as a true extension.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help at first! I found a first solution myself today:

`{{ _dirname(page) }}` doesn't work either, because `dirname`is related to the layout file where I created my navigation. It does work if I use `page.dirname`.

My code now looks like

```
<ul class="navigation-level-1">        
    <li class="item-level-1 {% if basename == "page" %}current{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% if dirname != 'root' %}../{% endif %}page.html" class="text-level-1">
            Guild
        </a>
        <ul class="navigation-level-2">
            <li class="item-level-2">
                <a href="{% if page.dirname != "www/subfolder" %}subfolder/{% endif %}subpage.html" class="text-level-2">subpage</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But the Problem with this is, that I cannot get into subpages from other pages if i entered one subpage. I hope someone can understand what i mean :D

I try to visualize:

```
* Page A
** Subpage A
* Page B
** Subpage B
```

If I entered Subpage A and I want to visit Subpage B i can't do so because my solution just works if I am on the root, you know?

Any ideas? :)

Comment: probably not a good idea to ask a question as part of your answer; better post a new question

Comment: Sounds like you want the relative paths from one page to another? We just should be able to create a swig tag for this. I suggest creating a feature request here: https://github.com/assemble/swig-extensions/issues

Comment: thanks! created the issue here: https://github.com/assemble/swig-extensions/issues/1